# Flex Builder 4 mobile modifying app properties

Tags: icons, mobile-phones, title, flex4.5

I am building an app in Flex Builder 4 (iOS and Android) and have my app worked almost to completion and about ready for deployment. Unfortunately, I cannot find how to change the app icon and title for the system to read, so my app still shows up as `Main` with the default package symbol in the launcher. Does anyone know where to apply changes to these properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit these details in the `.xml` file for your project. It will be located in the root of your `src` folder and will be named something like `MyProject-app.xml`. Double click this, there you can edit the filename, version number, icon, etc.

NOTE: the default view is `Design`, i found it much easier to edit in the `Source` view.

Comment: this is Narasimha my problem is same i am try to this way but not editable mode and not change this xml file how can give writable permission this xml file please forward some solution